# How to write a C function that keeps reading a set of line and marks the length of the lines

Tags: c, function

I was trying an exercise in K&R which asks to write a program which reads a set of text line and prints the longest line.

I writing along the lines of something like this;

```
define a string of characters
write a function that marks the length of line until there's a newline
when encountered newline, the function again repeats
keep copying length to a variable if the length of newline is greater
copy the string (if of greater length) to another string
print the last copied string
```

I tried writing the function this mark the length which is certainly wrong

```
int getlength(char str[],int lim)
{
    int length ,c;
    c = getchar();
    while((c=getchar())!= '\n')
    {
        for (length=0; length < lim -1; length++)
            c = str[length];
    }
    return length;
}
```

Can anyone suggest me how to write the getlength function. I am not asking for the code but instead the psuedocode would be very helpful.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "*mark the length*" or what your function is supposed to do.

Comment: Oh what I meant was it stores the length of its characters in a variable

Comment: What do you mean by "*its characters*"?

Comment: The characters of input string. I admit I should have been clearer.

Comment: What do you mean by "*input string*"?

Comment: @melpomene I don't get it. I tried defining an array of characters and used a for loop to input characters into each string element. I guess that was the input string.

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. If you want to compute the length of a string, `strlen` does that, but I have no idea how that relates to your code or your last comment.

Comment: You have two answers. Is either of them what you are looking for?

Comment: @anonymoose yes strlen() is the kind of thing I was looking for but my question was how to write the code myself to compute the length of a line (that is length of string until a newline is there).

Comment: Ok. That is not clear from what you are asking. You talk about the whole program's intended operation but only show one function's code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I think you're looking for from reading the post and your comments:

```
int getlength(char str[],int lim)
{
    int length = 0;
    int c;
    while((c=getchar())!= '\n') //Get a character. If it's a newline, quit. Otherwise, keep going.
    {
        str[length] = c; //Add it to the string
        length++; //Move to the next character
    }
    str[length] = '\0'; //Add the terminating null to the end of the string
    return length;
}
```

This function will find the length of the first line you give it on stdin.

Here's why your original function did not work:

You had:

```
int getlength(char str[],int lim)
{
    int length ,c;
    c = getchar();
    while((c=getchar())!= '\n')
    {
        for (length=0; length < lim -1; length++)
            c = str[length];
    }
    return length;
}
```

First, the character you read with `c = getchar();` never gets processed because the while statement overwrites it while checking its condition. Remember, while loops will check the condition at the start of every loop. I think you wanted to use `do {...} while(condition);`, but if you do that you'll run into bugs because if the user types nothing the first getchar() call will return '\n' and the loop will run anyway and add it to the string.

Second, the inner loop loops over every character in the string you pass it and sets it to the most recently character read. I tried your code with a 100 character string and typed in "abcdef." I got 99 f's - it looped through each character in "abcdef" and set the whole string to the current character, and since 'f' was the last character, it was put in last.

Third, you didn't add a terminating null to the end of the string.

Comment: yes that was exactly the kind of answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

With strlen() you can get the length of the string. (I think that it is what you are asking)

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strlen.htm

Answer (score 1):

Okay i understood. You want to print the longest line from a text file. Here is your code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define LINEMAX 200
int main(){
    FILE * fp = fopen("longestline.in","r");
    char temp1[LINEMAX]={'\0'},temp2[LINEMAX]={'\0'},*selected,*longest,c;
    int longestLength=0,length=0;
    selected = temp1;
    while((c=fgetc(fp))!=EOF){
        while(c!='\n'&&c!=EOF){
            selected[length] =c;
            length++;
            c=fgetc(fp);
        }

        if(length>longestLength){
            longestLength = length;
            selected[length+1] = '\0';
            longest = selected;
            selected = selected == temp1 ?temp2:temp1;
        }
        length =0;

    }
    puts(longest);
return 0;
}
```